# Python Pandas Seaborn - bar chart / histogram with two columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the next dataframe in pandas-

```
Perpetrator Perpetrator     Gender
Age         Sex
1    2   Female
2    2   Female
3    3   Female
4    5   Female
5    7   Female
6    7   Female
7    7   Female...
```

where:

- Perpetrator Age means the age of the Perpetrator
- Gender means the perpetrator gender and
- Perpetrator Sex mean the amount of perpetrators of that gender

**for example - there are 5 female perpetrators that are 4 years old.**

I am trying to make a seaborn bar chart that has two sides (columns) - one for female and one for male, and see the amounts of each age.

tried using-

```
g = sns.catplot(x="Perpetrator Age", y="Perpetrator Sex",col="Gender",
                data=final_df5, saturation=.5,
                kind="bar")
```

and

```
sns.displot(penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", col="sex", multiple="dodge")
```

(from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) )

but nothing seems to work.
I keep getting this error -

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Perpetrator Age'

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get when you try:

```
print(df.columns)
```

You want it to look like:

```
Index(['Perpetrator Age', 'Perpetrator Sex', 'Gender'], dtype='object')
```

But, it looks like you may have heirarchical-indexed data. If you don't and it looks like above, you can try this seaborn plotting code:

```
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.catplot(x='Perpetrator Age', y="Perpetrator Sex", hue="Gender",
                data=df,saturation=.5, dodge=True, ci=None,kind="bar")
```

You need to change the `col=` to `hue=` in your code, and set `dodge=True`.

Result from random data.:

[image: catplot result]

**EDIT**

It looks like your dataframe's index is the Perpetrator's Age. To solve your issue reset the index and then plot (this time the code plot's the genders in two separate plots):

```
final_df5. reset_index(inplace=True)

import seaborn as sns

g = sns.catplot(x='Perpetrator Age', y="Perpetrator Sex",
                col='Gender', color='blue',
                data=final_df5, dodge=True,
                ci=None, kind="bar")
```

Result:

[image: edited result chart]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried using this code -

sns.catplot(x='Perpetrator Age', y="Perpetrator Sex", hue="Gender",
                data=final_df5,saturation=.5, dodge=True, ci=None, kind="bar")


but still getting this error - 
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Perpetrator Age'

even when changing hue to col

Comment: As I said at the beginning of the answer -- what is the output of `print(final_df5.columns)`?

Comment: Index(['Perpetrator Sex', 'Gender'], dtype='object')


I am looking to have actually two graphs side by side - one for men and one for women.
thanks!

Comment: thank you so much! can I choose the number of bar there? cuz it gives me 0-99 bars, can I make to be grouped somehow without changing the data?

Comment: The number of bars is set by the data in the 'Perpetrator Age' column. But you can set the xaxis limits to whatever you want with the `plt.xlim()` function.